# Print the part of the text in reverse order

Tags: python

I want to print the part of the text in reverse order.
Help, why is my code not working?

```
s = 'abch12345h'
print(s[3:9:-1])
```

Comment: It's `::` i.e. `print(s[3:9][::-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your stepping backwards your starting and ending index needs to switch place like this

```py
print(s[9:3:-1])

>>> h54321
```

Here's a good related answer: [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Answer (score 0):

Done! If the stride is negative, then the start index must be more than the end index.
Is will work:

```
print(s[9:3:-1])
```

Comment: There's no need to answer your own question when an equivalent acceptable answer is already given. Just click the check mark on the left to accept it.

Comment: I would agree that this is a redundant answer, but I'm glad you found what you needed :)

Comment: I agree. I didn't know about Mandera's answer when I was writing my answer. The different is 3 minutes. Thanks!